# Form text field is too wide for the side bar

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I created custom block for my entity and I want to add this entity creation form to the 2nd sidebar. I managed to do this and this is how it looks like now:

[image]

First textfield goes out of bounds, where as second one, which is textarea type, is okay. After looking at [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/), I realized that textarea is re-sizable and textfield is not. How can I solve this? If I put title as text area it doesn't look that nice so I would be very happy if I could stick to textfield and make it fit somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the #size attribute if you are creating the field from `hook_form` function in custom module.Below is the example

```
$form['level_of_effort'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Level of Effort'),
    '#description' => t('Level of Effort value must be between 0 and 100.'),
   ** '#size' => 3, **
    '#maxlength' => 3,
  );
```

or **you can do the css**, using the field selector and then applying "width:in px"

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can change field size .Default size is 60.You can text field width by css.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer, may I ask where did you find this form for text processing?

Comment: Are you create text field custom or by ui ? If you done this by ui then when you edit this field then this settings show

Comment: Can you Please Vote my answer .

Comment: By custom, not by ui

Comment: Read this and change your field size
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#textfield